# How to use a function to impose conditions on properties in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm really unsure what I'm doing here (new to JavaScript) but I know that I need the function to loop through each iteration of var schema and push it into var DB.
Here is my code so far:

```js
var schema = ["id", "name", "age"]

function model(add, object, schema) {
  var DB = {};
  for (var key in schema) {
    //i really don't know what code to put here that would take the 
    //conditions from model(below)and put it into var DB. This is 
    //where I am stuck.
  }
  return DB
}
model("add", {
      id: 1,
      name: "Joe",
      age: 32 "}, schema)
```

The return I am trying for is: DB //[{id: 1, name: "Joe", age: 32}]

Comment: *"The return I am trying for is..."* That's what you're feeding into `model`. What do you need the function for?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's a requirement of my course exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you're trying to do is filter an input object down to a predefined schema of keys: you're almost there! Your loop should attempt to find the keys from `schema` in the input `object` and add them to your `DB` object:

```
function model(add, object, schema) {
    var DB = {};
    for (var key in schema) {
      if (key in object) {
        DB[key] = object[key];
      }
    }
    return DB;
}
```

(As an aside, you might want to re-consider the variable name `object` as it's a built-in keyword.)

Comment: thank you! glad to know I'm almost there, Ive been looking at this for so long I'm going crosseyed.